# How to call methods in ApplicationController from other controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have protected function that gets and sets the current_user.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    end

    def current_user=(user)
      @current_user = user
      session[:user_id] = user.nil? ? user : user.id
    end
end
```

However, when I sign in, the current_user= method isn't called.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def sign_in
    if (@mailbox = Mailbox.find_by(email: params[:email], password: params[:password]))
      current_user= @mailbox.user
      redirect_to mailboxes_path
    else
      redirect_to :root
    end
 end
end
```

Also, the value of current_user is nil in other classes.
How do I make sure that the methods defined in ApplicationController are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current_user` method is an *instance* method, not a *class* method. Therefore, to access it, you need to invoke the method on the *instance* of the controller, which is `self`:

```
self.current_user = @mailbox.user
```

For further illustration, compare the following:

```
# This is a class method
def self.foo
    return 'bar'
end

# This is an instance method
def foo
    return 'bar'
end
```

The former method is on the class, while the latter is on *an instance* of the class. Therefore, they are respectively invoked in the following way:

```
# Invoking the class method
foo
#=> bar

# Invoking the instance method
self.foo
#=> bar
```

Comment: If this answer helped resolve your question, please consider accepting it as correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling your method by doing

```
current_user = @mailbox.user
```

Instead, you're setting a local variable called current_user. If you want to call your controller method you need to say:

```
self.current_user = @mailbox.user
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method):

```
helper_method :current_user, :current_user=
```

and remove `current_user` method from private.